# MySQL not and not equal operators fail, what gives?

Tags: mysql, not-operator

I have a table T that has a column A.  A started with a default of NULL.  40 rows later, I changed the default to 1.  Three rows had a value of 2.  I tried to select all the rows where column A where not 2 and set them to the new default of 1 (which hadn't happened automatically when I altered the table).  I first tried:

```
update T set A=1 where A != 2;
```

Nada.  Didn't work.  Selected zero rows.  Next I tried:

```
update T set A=1 where !(A=2);
```

Nope, nothing there either.  I tried plugging them into selects, to see if there was something wrong with the update, but those returned nothing either.  The MySQL reference manual says that != and ! are valid operators and ought to be perfectly valid in that context.  I finally achieved my goal using IS NULL, but those statements **should** have worked.  So what gives?  Why didn't that work?

I am running MySQL version: 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.6 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
update T set A=1 where A != 2 or A is null;
```

Comparisons involving `NULL` evaluate to [`NULL(UNKNOWN)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html) and will thus never be true.

Comment: Mentioned in the question that I already achieved my goal using IS NULL.  Meaning, I already did that.

But thanks for the bit about comparisons involving NULL!